# FastAI : Getting Prediction of Image from Learner

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I want to be able to predict the Class of a Single Image from the Learner and i always get an Index Out of Bound Exception .
Here is the Code

```
data = ImageDataLoader.from_folder(path, train="Train", valid ="Valid",
        ds_tfms=get_transforms(), size=(256,256), bs=32, num_workers=4)
//Model is a Sequential One 
learn = Learner(data, model, loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(), metrics=accuracy)// The Model
learn.fit_one_cycle(100, lr_max=3e-3)
Img = //PIL Image Path
learn.predict(img)
```

The Model is able to Predict on ImageDataLoader but not on a Single Image .If anyone has any clue it would be much appreciated
Here is a Link to FastAi but didnt solve the issue
https://forums.fast.ai/t/how-to-use-learner-predict-list-index-out-of-range/81998/7

EDIT NOTE : I have tried to convert the Image to a tensor Flow but another error is given .[Photo of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p3np.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that `data` is a rank 4 tensor whereas `Img` is rank 3. In other words, it is missing the #points or batch dimension up front. In TF one can fix that with [`tf.expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) like so

```
img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
```

or fixing it when passing to the model

```
learn.predict(tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0))
```

You can also look at `tf.newaxis` (see the second code example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced)).

Comment: Thanks for your response .I have tried opening with PIL Image.open(Image Path ) and then expand_dims but i get this error .                                                                                  
Attempt to convert a value (<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=256x256 at 0x7F825E6A0950>) with an unsupported type (<class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>) to a Tensor.

Comment: Also When i print (type(testingdata.train_ds [0][0] )) . The result is "fastai.vision.core.PILImage"  .Hope this info helps

Comment: Clearly, you need to convert the PIL object to a TF Tensor. Did you try `img = tf.Tensor(img)`?

Comment: Okay , i have tried this , Please See the Error that was given to me in the Questions Body Above and tell me what you think of it .